# NSData initWithContentsOfURL: does not return the original allocation?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, memory-management, nsdata, foundation

In the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of `NSData`'s `initWithContentsOfURL:`, it says:

> The returned object might be different than the original receiver.

What are the implications of that? It seems to imply that a standard "alloc/init" line could leak memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are several reasons why - class clusters being the most publicly recognized:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        NSData * result =
           [[NSDataClassClusterSpecialization alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [self release];
        return result;
    }
    return self;
}
```

no leaks are introduced using this form.

it just means that you should only use the result of the `alloc`+`init` call (rather than holding onto the result of `alloc`), which is a good idea in any case -- even when not explicitly documented.